# Multiple schema in typescript orm

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, orm, typeorm

In our Postgres DB I have multiple schemas with identically structured tables that represent two version of the same model - one that represents files that are active and the other represents files that were archived.

For example:
Active schema   Files table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| ... | ... |
| ... | ... |

Archive schema   Files table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| ... | ... |
| ... | ... |

In our Node.js server, I used TypeORM until now and I want a way that our TypeORM model/entity can connect to both tables in the different schemas since they are the same models (classes) with the same fields.

As far as I can tell, TypeORM only supports one schema per connection and the schema must be declared upon the creation of the connection (inside the model file).

I am looking for a different ORM for TypeScript in which you can dynamically change the schema name during runtime and reuse the same models and repositories.